# ExtJS4 toolbar issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I am new to ExtJS4.I have one doubt,if we add buttons to toolbar buttons are arranged from left side.Is it possible to add buttons from right side?

Actually toolbar is using box layout so i think we need to change options in Box.js.I tried a lot to get the solution.But i am not able to find where it is specifying from left side.Can anyone please help me.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the man said, with a stretched layout 1,2 will be at the right side.

```
<table width="100%">
<tr><td width="100%">&nbspl;</td><td>1</td><td>2</td</tr>
</table>

Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
   ...
   items: [ '->',
            { text: '1' }, 
            { text: '2' } ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding '->' before the first item which should be on the right side.